# automate export from excel to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, excel, csv

I have a series of reports that I have incoming daily and would like to automate the process. So far I have the emails being pushed to a folder and a python script to format them for key matching within the database and re-writing to a new file. I am stuck on the process for exporting the csv file to the MySQL. Any ideas?

Comment: So you could generate the CSV ready but unable to insert into MySQL?

Comment: I want to automate the insert into MySQL. I think I am going to take another route and just use python's MySQL package and add onto the script. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Automate the insert into mysql from CSV:

**Install mysql-python:**

```
pip install mysql-python
```

**The script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import MySQLdb

mysql_conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='user', 
                             passwd='password', db='your_db_name')
mysql_cursor = mysql_conn.cursor()

f = open('/path/to/file.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    mysql_cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO test (col1, col2, col3) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)""",
                         (row[0], row[1], row[2]))


mysql_conn.commit()
mysql_cursor.close()
```

`#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of the file makes it easy to execute the python file from terminal.

Save this file somewhere like: `/home/username/bin/csv_to_mysql.py`

Mark it as executable: `chmod +x /home/username/bin/csv_to_mysql.py`

Then run it directly from terminal: `/home/username/bin/csv_to_mysql.py`